# How do objects turn into arrays?

Tags: javascript, html

Example：

```
obj={"name":"111","age":"1111"}
```

become

```
["name":"111","age":"111"]
```

How do you do it? I don't know what to do

Comment: your array is not valid with colons.

Comment: Umm... you change "{}" to "[]"?

Comment: The latter is incorrect syntax, it does not work at all in JavaScript

Comment: Just use `[].concat(obj)` if you want an array with your object.

Comment: yes,{} become[],Can not you

Answer (score 0):

**Array is ordered data structure (one of a Object) ! if you added array to property keys like this example array.length becomes 0 (lost index values). so don't use property keys with arrays ! use array to build up a ordered data structure **

```js
var obj = {"name":"111","age":"1111"};
var arr = [];

for(var prop in obj){
 
 arr[prop] = obj[prop];
  
};

now arr becomes => [name: "111", age: "1111"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Although, I would just use Object Syntax, you may want to see this:

```js
var what = [];
what['really'] = "That's crazy!";
what['yes'] = 'Awesome';
what['number'] = 10;
console.log(what instanceof Array);
for(var i in what){
  console.log(i+' =', what[i]);
}
```

I saw crazy code like this in a book I bought. Note that the length property is not automatically defined with this Syntax, hence the for in loop. It looks, unlike regular Objects, like index order is preserved.